# Date update in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Team,
I had an issue in SQL DATE.

I had a filed X_RECEIVED_DATE=1/1/753.

Im trying to update that field as below

```
update table_contract set x_received_date=
to_date(TO_CHAR(X_RECEIVED_DATE-24/24,'mm/dd/yy hh:mi:ss PM')) where objid=268865360
```

IM trying to update a field with this but it is throwing and error 
" ORA-01843: not a valid month"

Please help me over this and provide me some quick ideas pls

Comment: What is `X_RECEIVED_DATE-24/24` supposed to give you?

Comment: X_RECEIVED_DATE--TO_CHAR(X_RECEIVED_DATE-24/24,'MM/DD/YYHH:MI:SSPM')
    1/1/1753          12/31/52 12:00:00 AM

Comment: this is the output if i query
select X_RECEIVED_DATE, TO_CHAR(X_RECEIVED_DATE - 24 / 24, 'MM/dd/yy hh:mi:ss PM') from table_contract where objid=268865360

Comment: what is the date that you want it set to?

Comment: So you're just subtracting one day?  Then why write it as 24/24?

Comment: `update table_contract set x_received_date=X_RECEIVED_DATE-24/24 where objid=268865360`

Answer (score 1):

So here's what you seem to be doing:

- Subtracting one day (using `24/24`) from the date
- Converting it to a string with a specific format
- Converting it *back* to a date but not specifying a format

My guess is the database is not able to infer the format when it tries to parse the date.  However *there's no need to convert it to a string and back* that I can see.

You should be able to just do:

```
UPDATE table_contract 
SET x_received_date = x_received_date-1
WHERE objid=268865360
```

Based on your comment, you're trying to show that parsing a date with a two-digit year will not give you the original date back.  If that's the case then just specify the date format when parsing:

```
to_date(
       TO_CHAR(X_RECEIVED_DATE-24/24
               ,'mm/dd/yy hh:mi:ss PM')
       ,'mm/dd/yy hh:mi:ss PM')
```

Comment: thing is my previous date = 1/1/1753 when i convert it to string , it will be 12/31/52 12:00:00 AM when i convert it back to date and updating is showing as '12/31/2052' so, i want to prove how '12/31/52' is converting as '12/31/2052' i know this being done automatically, as we are restricting it to YY and by updating it will take the default century and will turn to 2052. But i need to show the results like how it get transformed.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting an integer from a `date` field will give you a `date` - there's no reason to convert it to a `char` and then back to a `date` again:

```
UPDATE table_contract 
SET    x_received_date = X_RECEIVED_DATE - 24/24
WHERE  objid = 268865360
```

Comment: thing is my previous date = 1/1/1753

when i convert it to string , it will be 12/31/52 12:00:00 AM

when i convert it back to date and updating is showing as '12/31/2052'

so, i want to prove how '12/31/52' is converting as '12/31/2052'
i know this being done automatically, as we are restricting it to YY and by updating it will take the default century and will turn to 2052. But i need to show the results like how it get transformed.